# AdSense not working with Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, adsense, turbolinks

I keep getting

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://lolfantasy.net/ from frame with URL http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-874208342468282…535&u_cd=24&u_nplug=8&u_nmime=81&biw=1520&bih=454&fu=0&js=uds&eid=37464000. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

when using adsense with Turbolinks.

I'm using the code from this [page](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_adsense.html). It still doesn't work. The ad shows for a split second sometimes but disappears afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution using Turbolinks 5

Head

```
<script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" data-turbolinks-eval="false"></script>
```

Body
Adsense code

```
 <ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXX"
 data-ad-slot="XXX"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
```

Javascript

```
function adsenseAds() {
var ads = document.querySelectorAll('.adsbygoogle');

ads.forEach(function(ad) {
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
});
}

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', adsenseAds);
```

Comment: I was in doubt, because everywhere they write that AdSense doesn't work with Turbolinks, but it looks like that your solution works!

Comment: Well, after futher testing I have to curb my enthusiasm, because it looks like AdSense is not tracking clicks with this implementation correctly. I switched to DFP which works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this article and see if that can help you.

http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_adsense.html

The key part is on page:fetch they are clearing the ads (Example in CoffeeScript)

```
clearAds: ->
    @ads = {}
    window.google_prev_ad_slotnames_by_region[''] = '' if window.google_prev_ad_slotnames_by_region
    window.google_num_ad_slots = 0
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.